# IPhone App : not able to validate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, xcode4

I am not able to validate my IPhone App

It is giving erroe as shown  below

[image]

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it by
[link](http://www.artin.org/geekblog/2011/03/xcode-4-problem-submitting-app-with-static-library/)